# Code to ensure that at least one checkbox is checked : Doesn't work in Chrome or Firefox

Tags: jquery

I have a checkbox list for weekdays and I want to make sure that at least one day is selected at all times. I've created the following code but it doesn't seem to work correctly. In IE 8 it works but intermittently and in chrome and firefox it doesn't work at all. Can any one explain what I'm doing wrong?

Cheers

Pete

```
$(function () {

    var weekdays = $("input[name='WeekDays']");

    $(weekdays).change(function (e) {

        var count = $(weekdays).filter(":checked").length;

        if (count < 1) {

            e.preventDefault();

        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `change` event is called **after** the state has changed, so preventing the default action at this stage does not prevent unselecting it.

However, you could programatically select the checkbox again.

```
if (count < 1) {
    this.checked = true;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kH3jM/)

Note that `weekdays` is already a jQuery object, so there is no sense in passing it to jQuery again.

Comment: From what I recall, IE fires the change event when the value changes, whereas Firefox and Chrome fire the change event when the checkbox loses focus and the value has changed. Working with the click event instead is generally the best solution, though there are potential downsides.

Comment: @Anthony: No, Firefox and Chrome will also fire the change event directly. Only text boxes fire the change event when they loose focus and the value changed (you can try it in the demo). The big downside of listening to the `click` event is that changes made via the keyboard or other input devices won't be recognized.

Comment: Answer goes to @felix. Interestingly, I can get the my original version to work consistently in IE8 as as I call blur() on the checkbox after calling preventDefault(). This suggests that there is a difference in the way IE and the other browsers handle state changes.